# how to call a function inside a controller from a script block of html in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using the Jquery code inside angularjs Controller and calling a function inside that controller. But It is not calling that function and I am getting error called "Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteMedication is not defined".

```
confirm(medication_id) {
        console.log(medication_id);
        $(".confirm").popover({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            content: '<p><a type="button" class="btn next-btn popup-btns" onclick="deleteMedication(this.medication_id);">Yes</a><a type="button" class="btn cancel-btn mrgn-L10 popup-btns" onclick="hideConfirm()">No</a></p>',
            placement: 'left',
            html: true

        });
    }


    /**
     * Delete Medication Details
     * @param  {Number} medication_id This is the medication id that needs to be passed
     */
    deleteMedication(medication_id) {
        this.VitalInformationService.deleteMedication(this.AuthService.getParticipantDashboardId(), medication_id).then(data => {
            /*Notification for Diagnosis Deletion*/
            this.ngToast.create({
                content: 'Medication Deleted Successfully.',
                className: 'danger',
                dismissButtonHtml: '&times',
                dismissOnTimeout: true,
                timeout: 3000
            });
            //List of Medication
            this.VitalInformationService.listMedication().then(data => {
                this.medications = data;
            }, error => {
                console.log("Error in fetching Medication")
            });

        });
    }
```

I tried calling with "this.deleteMedication(this.medication_id)" also. But it is not working. Can anybody give the solution...

Comment: Try `ng-click="deleteMedication(this.medication_id)"`, not `onclick`

Comment: you have to $compile popup content. You can't provide raw string for it.

Comment: I have used ng-click also. Nothing is happening

Comment: @lujcon is right, it should be either compiled by hand or be a part of ng-controller or some directive

Comment: Can you please give us your file with angular code? And html

Comment: We are using ES6 here and also webpack to build it.. If I share it you need to install all node dependencies

Comment: I know that it's not the direct answer but $compile is an advanced topic. Maybe instead of using jQuery plugins is better to use "native" angular components - ex: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/